# simple django code snippet from file upload

Tags: python, django, file-upload

sorry for dumb question.

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

what happens really in the background when i bind the request to the Form?

Comment: it's pretty much the same as any other django form validation except you're using the request.FILES data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates an empty form to be passed to the template upload.html since the previous form in upload.html did not pass the validation. When a form has some error, Validation Error exception is raised, then the form is invalid, or when the view is called and request does not include the method POST therefor you must render it again.